# WebView not showing content

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

all.

I'm having some trouble displaying a url content gotten from a EditText field, on a WebView on Android.

I just want to add a String inserted into an EditText field, to open a url on another activity, where a webView opens with the Google search url, searching for the given text in EditText.

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.hbt.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText term;
    String query;
    WebView intview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    term = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
    query = term.getText().toString();

    intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
}

public void openWikipedia(View intview){

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Wikipedia.class);
     intent.putExtra("query", query);
     startActivity(intent);
    }

public void openGoogle(View view){

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Google.class);
     intent.putExtra("query", query);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my Google.java:

```
package com.hbt.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View; 
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Google extends Activity {
String query;
WebView intview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);
}

public void opengoogle (View webView1){
    intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    intview.loadUrl("https://www.google.pt");

    String query = "";

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert a search item.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (bundle != null) {
        query = bundle.getString("query");
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
}
```

And finally, the Wikipedia.java:

```
package com.hbt.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Wikipedia extends Activity {

    String query;
WebView intview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wikipedia);
}

 public void openWikipedia (View view){
     intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     String query = "";
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (bundle == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert a search item.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     if (bundle != null) {
         query = bundle.getString("query");
     }

     String url = "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search="+ query;
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
     startActivity(i);

}   

    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
         onBackPressed();
         return true;
     }
     else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
}
}
```

I really can't understand why the WebView doesn't show the content. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

As asked, here goes the Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Google"
    android:minEms="6"
    android:onClick="openWikipedia"
    android:text="@string/wikipedia" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="openGoogle"
    android:text="@string/google" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="@string/text_to_search_" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next the Wikipedia layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Google XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

They are different because I was trying to approach the matter form several fronts.

Comment: Did you add the INTERNET permission to your app's manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did. Added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> next to the <uses-sdk /> tag.

Comment: It just shows a blank screen. I see the Zoom controls when I press on the view, but nothing is loaded.

Comment: can you post your layout xml as well? it looks like you are declaring the EditText and getting a value from it before it is set.

Comment: @adavis, Just posted the XML files above.

Comment: Seems like you don't even need the extra activities. You can do this just with one activity.

Comment: @KumarBibek, This is an assignment for a class I'm taking, where we are supposed to use more than one activity, just to understand how activities communicate with each other and pass data between them. Would like to understand the logic of the code itself.

Comment: I would suggest to first make it work with one activity, and then move on to using multiple activities.

Comment: @KumarBibek. Running on one activity worked. I now want to call a full screen webview on Google and Wikipedia activity and this is where I got in trouble. I can't successfully pass the data to the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The only things that you would want is the **MainActivity** and the **main_activity.xml**.

The other things, you don't really need as far as I can see.

Here's the code listing of the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText term;
    String query;
    WebView intview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        term = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        query = term.getText().toString();

        intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }

    public void openWikipedia(View intview) {
        String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + query;
        this.intview.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void openGoogle(View view) {
        String url = "https://www.google.pt?q="+query;
        this.intview.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Now, the main activity's layout. No changes required as compared to the original one you have. But, for clarity, I am posting it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Google"
    android:minEms="6"
    android:onClick="openWikipedia"
    android:text="Wikipedia" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="openGoogle"
    android:text="Google" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Wikipedia"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Google"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="Text to search" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchtext"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, once you press the button, Google or Wikipedia, your webview should start loading the display the content on it. Give it some time.

**For Wikipedia:** I noticed, it has redirects, so finally, it will open the new URL in the default browser. You will need to handle this.

**For Google:** The URL is probably not setup correctly, but you could look into it.

Though, the main problem of the **WebView** not loading properly should be fixed now.

--------------------Update-------------------------------

Now, change these things:

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText term;
    String query;
    WebView intview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        term = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        query = term.getText().toString();

        intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }

    public void openWikipedia(View intview) {
        String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + query;
        this.intview.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void openGoogle(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Google.class);
        intent.putExtra("query", term.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Google.class**

```
public class Google extends Activity {
    String query;
    WebView intview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);
        opengoogle();
    }

    public void opengoogle() {
        intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        intview.loadUrl("https://www.google.pt");

        String query = "";

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert a search item.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (bundle != null) {
            query = bundle.getString("query");
            intview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com?q=" + query);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right on the spot. I now only face the problem of, once I'm on the Google activity, if I press one of the buttons, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your onclick methods to get the current value of the EditText, before sending the intent: **query = term.getText().toString();**

```
public void openWikipedia(View intview){
     query = term.getText().toString();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Wikipedia.class);
     intent.putExtra("query", query);
     startActivity(intent);
    }

public void openGoogle(View view){
     query = term.getText().toString();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Google.class);
     intent.putExtra("query", query);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Set up the webviews in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);

    intview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    intview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    intview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    intview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    intview.loadUrl("https://www.google.pt");

    String query = "";

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert a search item.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (bundle != null) {
        query = bundle.getString("query");
    }

}
```

That should work.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but no go. Webview is blank. And I had the term.getText().toString() in the onCreate method.

Comment: In your oncreate methods you also should set up the web views.

Comment: No changes, yet. I've seen some problems with the code, but I really can't figure out where to start. I believe it wasn't supposed to have openwikipedia() on both the mainActivity and the WikipediaActivity. But I can't figure out where and how to give the webview the address I want.